# PyGAD - how to create solution which will return me list of 0 and 1

Tags: python, pygad

I'm experimenting with pygad.
Have created initial population of lists of 0 and 1:

```
llist =  [[random.randint(0,1)  for _ in range(40)] for _ in range(10)]
```

my fitness functions does simple

sum(solution)

I'm trying to create model which will evolve list to contain only 1 i.e. [1,1,1,1.....1] as this is the best fitness for the population.
However, results of the population are floats ranging from -2 to +15.
Is there any way to restrict the solution values?

Is there any way to get solution to contain only list of 1 ?

Answer (score 2):

After looking into the documentation,
it turns out that gen_type=int and gene_space=[0,1] does the trick!

Comment: How can we keep number of 1's always fixed after every mutation?